# Performance counters change synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I have counters category that recreates each time when new counter added in runtime

```
private PerformanceCounter RegisterCounterInSystemFor(string metricName)
    {
        if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(countersCategoryName))
        {
            PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(countersCategoryName);
        }

        var newCounterCreationData = new CounterCreationData(
            metricName,
            string.Empty,
            PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64);

        currentlyCreatedCounters.Add(newCounterCreationData);
        PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(
            countersCategoryName,
            "counters for application",
            PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance,
            currentlyCreatedCounters);

        return new PerformanceCounter
        {
            CategoryName = countersCategoryName,
            CounterName = metricName,
            InstanceName = countersCategoryName,
            ReadOnly = false
        };
}
```

Also I have counters objects dictionary, which refreshes when category created

```
private Dictionary<string, PerformanceCounter> cachedCounters

private void RefreshCountersCache()
    {
        var counterNames = new List<string>(cachedCounters.Keys);
        foreach (var counterName in counterNames)
        {
            cachedCounters[counterName].Dispose();
            var counter = new PerformanceCounter
            {
                CategoryName = countersCategoryName,
                CounterName = counterName,
                InstanceName = countersCategoryName,
                ReadOnly = false
            };
            cachedCounters[counterName] = counter;
        }
    }
```

Then i try set RawValue for one of cached counters and nothing has happened in System Monitor.

```
public void Save(IEnumerable<Metric> metrics)
    {
        foreach (var metric in metrics)
        {
            if (!cachedCounters.TryGetValue(metric.Name, out var counter))
            {
                lock (syncObj)
                {
                    counter = RegisterCounterInSystemFor(metric.Name);
                    RefreshCountersCache();
                    cachedCounters[metric.Name] = counter;
                }
            }

            counter.RawValue = (long) metric.Value;
        }
    }
```

If I run this code step by step in debugger, value of counter changes. But when i try change other counter value of first also changes. It seems like all objects refer to one memory block

Thanks for your suggestions what to do with it. And sorry for my english